# Can a site be put in maintenance mode without a database?

Tags: 7, maintenance-mode

I'm trying to handle a planned database outage and want Drupal to show the maintenance page during that time.

- `$conf['maintenance_theme'] = 'exampletheme'` and a suitable `$conf['_message']` are set in my `sites/sitename.com/settings.php`
- I have a `maintenace-page--offline.tpl.php` and `maintenance-page.tpl.php` in `sites/all/themes/exampletheme/templates/`
- I set `$conf['maintenance_mode'] = TRUE` in `sites/sitename.com/settings.php`

I hope that Drupal that does not have a database can still bootstrap and display the contents of `maintenance-page--offline-tpl.php` in this configuration, but in my testing it seems that's not the case. Should this work? Anything I should look into?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165699/how-to-restore-complete-database-keeping-the-site-in-maintenance-mode-in-drupal ?

Comment: @brotherperes I've read through that now and followed the instructions and it seems it's not working. So, I guess this question is asking for help to understand why this feature is not working for me.

Comment: Well there is one way to find out, Are you thinking what I'm thinking?

Comment: yes. Clone the website to a different location first. I've got the process to do that if you need.

Comment: I'd say no you'd need a database working as the variable that defines if the site is/isn't in maintenance mode is itself stored in the database. 

A dirty but quick workaround would be to temporary hack the index.php and do a print 'Site in maintenance mode'; die; or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing should work: the `maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php` template should be called when the database is unavailable.

Drupal does not bootstrap completely when there is no database, but does so partially. When the bootstrap process fails to contact the database, it calls `_drupal_log_error()` in `include/errors.inc`, which (indirectly) calls `_drupal_maintenance_theme()` in `includes/theme.maintenance.inc.` This is enough to allow hook invocations to work, and to load the theme specified in your `$conf['maintenance_theme']` setting.

First, I would verify that `_drupal_maintenance_theme()` is being called and that it's finding your theme. If you're using a debugger, set a breakpoint there. If not, add this line at the end of the function:

```
  echo "<p>Custom theme: $custom_theme</p>";
```

If all is ok up to this point, try starting off with the simplest possible maintenance page in `maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php`, e.g.

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

If that works, and your maintenance page does not, perhaps your maintenance page contains something that attempts to access the database, or invokes a hook that attempts to access the database? Can you post your template and any errors you are seeing?

If the simple maintenance page doesn't work, more debugging would be needed.